# When to play a Knight card

Tags: catan

When can I play a Knight Card.

For example, when it's my turn, and I already have a knight card I have not played, can I use it if I do not have the robber on one of my hexes?

Or, if it's another players turn, and they place a robber one of my hexes, can I immediately counter them with one of my Knight cards, or do I have to wait until it's my turn to use it to remove the robber?

Comment: Welcome, to board & cardgames. 
Next time when you have two questions, please ask them as separate questions. In this case I could change them into a single question, so no need to change it now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf), you can play a Knight card in your turn if you want. But only in your turn.

> b) Playing Development Cards
>
> At any time during your turn, you may
>   play 1 Development Card (on the table).
>
> That card, however, may not be a card
>   you bought during the same turn!

Comment: I would add that you can also play the knight on your turn BEFORE you roll your dice :)